# 'I want to study all of them's subtitles.' - is that correct?

Tags: pronouns, possessives

Please tell me, can I say following:

> I got 10 movies and I want to study ALL OF THEM'S English subtitles.

My question refers to the words  **all of them's**. Can I say that or must I use the normal

> I got 10 movies and I want to study the English subtitles OF ALL OF THEM.

The meaning I want to convey is the emphasis on ALL OF THE MOVIES.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, you can say it.  (Unless you have been served with a court order prohibiting it.)  But  as noted in the answer, that is not the standard way to do it.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, Mr.Edgar, I'm happy to know now that my presumption was also ok. 

Comment: @GEdgar is not saying that it is correct.  He is saying that it is NOT standard.  An educated speaker would find that expression to be very incorrect.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. 

Answer (score 3):

The possessive form of **them** is **their**.

The sentence is better as

> I got 10 movies and I want to study all their English subtitles.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a prompt answer. I have one question, please, if you don't mind: In your sentence the emphasis is on all of the subtitles, whereas the meaning I wanted to convey was the emphasis on ALL OF THE MOVIES. As my explanation sentence shows:  'I got 10 movies and I want to study the English subtitles OF ALL OF THEM.'  So what do you think, is there any other sentence I can use to put the emphasis as I've just described it now ? Thank you.

Comment: You mention that you have 10 movies, so that is implicit in "their subtitles". Otherwise you would say for example "I got 10 movies and I want to study the English subtitles in one of them." Your second sentence is correct.

Comment: Ok, Weather Vane, thank you so much. One last question and I'm done:  Is my first sentence acceptable in colloquial English or is it a total no-go ? 

Comment: Anything might be said in colloquial English but that does make it grammatical.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. 

Answer (score 0):

1. In all the above cases Should it not be "**I have gotten**" or "**I have**"... ten movies... blah blah blah?
2. .. and I want to study all **of the** English subtitles.
   In your sentence you are using “Them” as an adjective. 
   "Them" and thus 'Their' can't be used as an adjective when the noun is an Object/thing. The main reason why there is confusion on this topic is due to the misunderstanding that when 'their' becomes an adjective it is an object to the subject noun, which have to be an essential being; the subject noun is not an object when you use the words 'their', 'they', 'them', etc.
   For guidance Adjectives used as a Determiner - An article (a, an, the), a number or amount, a possessive adjective (my, his, her, its, your, our, their), or a demonstrative (this, that, these, those).

Comment: (1) No; "I got" is colloquial British English, which uses *gotten* **very** rarely. (*Gotten* survived from the Pilgrim Fathers' time in their new environment, and is more-or-less extinct in Britain.) (2) No; your analysis would preclude a sentence like "I know there were three Bronte sisters and I like all of their books."

Comment: (1) No??: Being a Brit I don't know about much about the Pilgrim Fathers. I do know that gotten is well used in our area (colloquial British English). When using "got" it would be normally be preceded with have or followed by a description i.e. Today I got 10 movies from. I don't see or hear it being used as in the format above...You also did not address the second option "have". (2) How would it preclude the Bronte Sisters as they are referred to as people not objects.

Comment: As I commented, *gotten* survives in a very few BrE dialects. It's more-or-less extinct. Yours is obviously one where it does survive. However, to say that "I got" is incorrect is itself incorrect; it's the simple past tense, and simply means "I obtained" rather than "I possess" (which would be *I have got* in dialects where *gotten* is obsolete). (2) "I bought a house and cleaned its downstairs windows"; "I bought three houses and cleaned their dirty windows"; "I have three houses and I cleaned all of **their** windows, but not yours." All are idiomatic

Comment: Also the "I got" sentence could be part of the following sequence: We were all given presents today. I got 10 movies . . .

Comment: With 'I got 10 movies' I meant 'I have 10 movies'.